# Can date ranges in a Silverlight (Chart) LineSeries be compressed?

Tags: silverlight, charts

The x-axis in my chart is a date value. The y-axis is a positive integer. My dataset typically has lots of points over one or two days and then no data for a month or so. Then another two days of lots of activity, then another extended period of inactivity.

There's no pattern really to the data in terms of how long the periods of activity and inactivity are.

What I need to do is compress the x-axis in the areas in which there are no data points. So, the x-axis would not be constant-scale.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating your own custom axis or series..?